# Change image view content using picasso in a fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview

since yesterday I have tried to change the content of an imageView into a fragment but beautiful the button and it does nothing.

I would appreciate any help

Method used in the fragment:

```
    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when (v?.id) {
            R.id.nextButton -> {
                // val rnds = (0..99999).random()
                val quest1 = "https://My-web-get-image-url.com/"
                // var randomGetNumber = quest1 + rnds
                Picasso.get().load(quest1).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).into(memeRandomView)
                Picasso.get().setLoggingEnabled(true)
            }
            else -> {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My layaout

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/memeRandomView"
        android:layout_width="385dp"
        android:layout_height="452dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.578"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Next"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/memeRandomView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.434" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you get a reference for your views(nextButton,memeRandomView) using findViewById(),viewBinding,kotlin-ext , you can set a click like that and use picasso in the click listener:

```
 nextButton.setOnClickListener{
        Picasso.get()
            .load(url)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(memeRandomView)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, right now I will try